What was Furiosa doing with the motorcycle under the War Rig?
In Furiosa: A Mad Max Saga, there’s a scene in Chapter 3: The Stowaway in which the War Rig is attacked. Midway into the fight, we find Furiosa clinging to the underside of the War Rig (presumably why the chapter is called “The Stowaway”).
At this point, she appears to grab onto a chain connected to a motorcycle that has rolled under the War Rig and hangs onto it, dragging the motorcycle on the ground behind her. She holds onto it for a while until forced to release it to deal with other things.
Why was Furiosa clinging so desperately to the motorcycle?

It is a motorcycle she hid there to use in her escape.
You can see the covered up motorcycle just before the motorcycle that got pulled under the rig uncovers it:

The motorcycle that is being crushed tears away the hidden motorcycle's cover:

Then the hidden motorcycle gets loose from the rig, and Furiosa's stash of food (which you can see her hide there in the previous scene) also comes loose and falls away:

Also note the chain that was supposed to keep the motorcycle secured to the rig.

Thank you! All this happened so fast that I didn't catch the details.

Was there a scene where they showed Furiosa stashing the bike? IIRC there is a scene where a technician catches her stashing food, but if they showed her stashing the bike, I must have either spaced out for a moment or misinterpreted what I was seeing.

@Kevin When she's stashing the food you can see a glimpse of part of the bike, but you wouldn't recognize what it was.
